# Does triggering a biotic explosion on a Warp remove the Expose effect?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Expose upgrade for Warp has this effect:

> Increase weapon damage taken by a target by 15%.
>   Increase power damage taken by a target by 15% for 10 seconds.

We know from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/how-many-detonations-can-i-get-from-a-single-warp) that once a biotic explosion occurs after being set up by a Warp, it cannot be detonated again until a new Warp is applied. **Does this mean that the target is no longer "warped"? Does the Expose effect end once the explosion occurs?**

Comment: judging purely from playing a lot as a warp spammy adept, it doesn't seem so, but I have nothing else to back that up.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping. I use warp/throw a lot and I would feel better knowing that I'm not removing the debuff every time the BE is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoT effect of warp stays on target after detonation via Biotic Explosions. I got "warp" kills with asari adept after target survives Biotic Explosions.
Seems like Expose stays too. As long as i can judge damage outputs from pistol on Brutes that survived Biotic Explosions is bigger than on non exposed to warp Brutes. But there is always probability that this is effect from warp itself not from Expose Upgrade.
To carefully asses situation we need make an experiment on shielded non-armored target that can survive BE.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the coalesced.bin game file:

The "effectsremovedoncombo" field for biotic explosions contains: PowerCombo_Biotic Singularity Pull AntiGravity Ragdoll Stasis

The other 3 explosion types remove only their own PowerCombo effect.

So warp is unaffected in all of the explosion types.